# Illegal character(s) in message header field: Content-Type:

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

Following an API where it says that i need to send this POST request :

```
    POST https://api.vasttrafik.se/token HTTP/1.1
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
    Authorization: Basic UmJseEkyeTFsWVNFTTZ0Z2J6anBTa2E0R1o6Wk1nSkR0Y0pddaRGV4OTJldUxpQUdYOFExUnU=
    grant_type=client_credentials&scope=<device_id>
```

I am trying to build the corresponding POST-req in spring boot and this is what i come up with. However i end up with the error described in the title.. any ideas?

```
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.set("Content-Type:", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");


    headers.set("Authorization", "Basic UmJseEkyeTFsWVNFTTZ0Z2J6anBTa2E0R1o6Wk1nSkR0Y0paRGV4OTJldUxpQUdYOFExUnU=");

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> respEntity = restTemplate.exchange("https://api.vasttrafik.se/token", HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

    System.out.println(respEntity);
```

Comment: is the colon in `Content-Type` required? because you don't do the same for `Authorization`

Comment: It is because of the double colon; "Content-Type" -"Content-Type:"

Comment: Just delete the `:` in the `headers.set` call, it should be **only** `Content-Type` :wink:

Comment: true, removed it and another error came: 401 Unauthorized. What am i missing?

Comment: I don't know RestTemplate, but headers are not an entity. Check existing examples on how to do it. Do the same.

Comment: `grant_type=client_credentials&scope=<device_id>` should be the body of your `POST` request.

Comment: HTTP Status `401` means that you are unauthorized.